# How can I design the structure of a soul so that it cannot hold on to life energy?

Tags: mythical-creatures

When Jehovah create the universe, he left it to the angels to make life as they saw fit. To this end, he gave to them a portion of his power, the demiurge, which is the spark of life used to create the species that inhabit the universe. Each sex of angel, male and female, contain half of the demiurge inside them when they fuse together, the sparks combine, with humanity being born from the release of energy. Every human has a soul, a metaphysical container containing the life energy that allows us to live.

A sinister demon has kidnapped a male angel and immobilized him in unbreakable chains, intending to use him as an incubator for a new species. As this race is created with only half the demiurge, it results in an incomplete human being with only half a soul. These deformed monstrosities are called vampyres, and been produced in the hundreds. The half-human creatures have the intense desire to eat souls with the intention of completing their own.

Regardless of how many souls they consume, they are never able to full themselves permanently, the life energy eventually being lost. I need to come up with a reason for this. Two ideas I came up with are:

1. The soul is like a glass container, with life energy being water. Their is a hole in the bottom of the container, which causes the energy to slowly ooze out.
2. The soul of the aberration is too small a container, and unable to hold the capacity of energy that a fully formed soul can. (Eg: 100ml bottle versus 50ml bottle).

The problem is that neither ideas hold water under scrutiny. If the soul has a hole in it, the energy that the vampyre already had to start with would have leaked out already, causing it to be dead and unable to live in the first place. If the half soul is too small, it would be unable to take on any new energy at all, making feeding a waste.

How can I find an answer to this riddle?

Comment: You can make up almost anything for this. Example: the vampire soul is too small, so it uses other souls as a substitute/secondary battery, but the process is inefficient because souls try to resist the vampire and that depletes them faster. Their own soul doesn't do that, and so can function much longer despite the smaller size.

Comment: Since everything in this is fictitious it is entirely up to you what rules they use.

Comment: Also, doesn't "_demiurge_" already mean "_half-power_"?

Answer (score 1):

The love of one angel to another is the glue which holds the two halves of the demiurge together in the rendered soul.

The anger and fear of the chained angel has driven all love from his heart, so the spawned vampyres not only received merely half of a soul, they also received no love from their creator.

So even if they steal a half-soul from their victim, they cannot hold onto it.  It escapes and rejoins with Jehovah at the rising of the next dawn.  They lack the love needed to bind that half-soul to our world, and their victims (now half-soul vampyres themselves) certainly cannot provide it.

However, these lesser vampyres, the risen victims of the originals have some small measure of dark hope.  For during their lives as humans, they may have inspired another human to love them, and that human can provide them with the treasure that the originals can never find; a half-soul which loves and will stay bound to them.  Lesser vampyres can thus be cured, by killing someone who loves them.  They can become human again, but only at great cost, condemning their one true love to the endless hunger of being a vampyre.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of the "life energy" as a kind of gas, that is "particles" that have some internal energy. The more of that "particles" or "life energy" confined into a space the more internal energy (or momentum) they have. (Something like pressure) 
Now, a soul could be not a container but something like electromagnetic shield that does not allow the life energy to leak out of the body of the person. A half soul has a given fraction of the strength of a whole soul, thus you could push more energy into the body (or the container) but it will leak as the internal energy will be higher than what the half-soul can hold.

Answer (score 0):

The riddle can be solved by rethinking your two ideas. Forget about souls as containers and life energy leaking away. Propose something else that better fits your purpose.

If vampires devour souls, why not make the problem something as simple the devoured souls failing to "stick" to whatever it is inside a vampire they need to adhere to, after consumption, and then the souls become unstuck. The souls can then either leak out or flow away. A vampire will be a permanent state of soul deficiency. Although they might feel well-fed after consuming their latest soul.

In conclusion, if a concept doesn't work when it is scrutinized it's time to think of alternatives. This answer suggests one alternative, you are more than welcome to devise your own.